# Is it possible to determine if a power series represents a square integrable function without knowing the closed form of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, power-series

For example, suppose I had the series

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}x^m.
\end{equation}

We know this is the power series expansion for $e^{-x}$, which is square integrable on $[0,\infty]$.  Suppose I did not know the closed form of the power series above.  Is there any way to determine if $f(x)$ is square integrable (on $[0,\infty]$) from the coefficients of the power series?  If square integrability cannot be determined, is it at least possible to know if $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Another example, suppose I have a power series solution from a linear second order ODE.  Following the Frobenius method, suppose my solution to this ODE is of the form

\begin{equation}
g(x)= x^r \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_mx^m,
\end{equation}

with a complicated recurrence relation for the $a_m$ and $r$ is any real number.  Assume the closed form of the series is unknown or does not exist, but it converges absolutely for all $x$.  Can I determine if $g(x)$ is square integrable on $[0,\infty]$ or if $g(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ from the power series alone?